# initscript hadoop-0.20-mapreduce-tasktracker,action "start" failed

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-streaming, ubuntu-13.10, hadoop-plugins

initscript hadoop-0.20-mapreduce-tasktracker,action "start" failed. This is happening for namenode as well. I tried finding an answer but unable to do so. This happened when I tried installing task tracker using apt-get.

Comment: Without further information and error messages etc, it's almost impossible to help.